# How to use .aar files without gradle in Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, ant

I am trying to use [Calligraphy library by chrisjenx](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) in my ant based Intellij IDEA project. The example project and help file in the library mentions how to use it using gradle. I am not using gradle. Intellij IDEA doesn't permit to add .aar files dependency.

Can you please help me out?